# Why does the charge goes down the line?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, charge, conductors

Suppose we have two neutral charges connected by a conductor line. Now, we bring together two spheres with oppositely charges, and approximate it to our original system.

[image]

Now, imagine that we connect C and D by another line/wire, what exactly will happens?

I tried to answer this question as follow:
Since A and B have the same potential, we can call it $\phi$. Now, The potential of C near the sphere A is $\phi c>\phi$, and the D potential near the B sphere is $\phi d < \phi$, so that we have $\phi c > \phi d$. But, since we are dealing with conductors, $\phi c$ and $\phi d$ are the potentials throughout (constant through it) all the surface C and D, respectively.

When we connect C and D using a wire, since C has greater potential, the electric field in the wire will be directed down, from C to D. In Such way that, since electrons flow in the opposite direction of the electric field, they will rise up through the wire. So negative charge will flow from D to C.

[image]

But apparently, the answer is the opposite of the mine, the charge will goes down the wire. What is wrong with my attempt?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a very important detail while calculating the potential of the identical spheres C and D.

Initially they are neutral meaning they have equal number of oppo charged particles.

Lets consider of C for now (argument with D is exactly the same),
You bring the Sphere C close to A. What happens now? Charges in Sphere C will rearrange, but how? Such that some positive charges are closer to A. But since the C is neutral, the an equal amount of negative charges will move as well! Hence in the electrostatic condition, what you have is some positive charges on the surface towards A, while **equal** amount of opposite charges diametrically opposite. So then take the center of C and find the net potential there, because you have equal and opposite charges at diametrically opposite points, the **net potential inside Sphere C is ZERO!** (same for D)

Does it sound contradictory? Absolutely no.
Initially you had Sphere C at 0 Potential, now when you bring it closer to A the charges start rearraging, why does that happen? Since now Sphere A influences the Sphere C and so there is now a potential inside Sphere C, and the charges in C move so as to nullify this potential! Hence as we expect the end result would still have zero potential!

Now then if I connect C and D with a wire, what is the direction of current?
This situation is **no longer ELECTROSTATICS** because charges are moving.

> The fact that Conductor has the same potential everywhere ONLY holds in electrostatics

Here you not supposed to look at the net Potential, instead look at the **local Potential** i.e. Potential just about the two points where you connect the wire to the two spheres. You will now find that the local potential near wire at C is NEGATIVE (because of accumulation of electrons) and using similar argument local potential at the wire for D is POSITIVE.

And since electrons flow from negative to positive i.e. from C to D.

Comment: But as far as I understand the question, C and D are not neutral, they are the ones that have the initial charge on them. A and B are neutral as they are connected by the wire. So according to your answer, charges are induced on C and D by 'neutral' conductors A and B, which as you know is incorrect.

Comment: Exact, C and D are the charged bodies.

Comment: Ahh sorry... You are right... I got confused between the the charged sources. Well, it that case your argument @LSS is absolutely right. Otherwise there would be a violation of energy conservation. So my guess is you might probably has misinterpreted the question, in which I could suggest you to post the question as it is (with the same wordings) or add the source of the question if its openly available online.